# How to access DataGridCell from its child control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with template column, containing a checkbox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foreign key">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                IsChecked="{Binding ForeignKey,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                PreviewMouseDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I access a DataGridCell containing this checkbox from inside the handler (CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown), having only CheckBox as sender:

```
private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the UI control, iterate through the visual tree using a [helper](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent). Or, if you just need the databinding, use the Tag property of the CheckBox.

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          IsChecked="{Binding ForeignKey,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          PreviewMouseDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown"
          Tag="{Binding}" />
```

Then you can access it in your code, and typecast it to the type of the bound item(s).

Comment: Thanks, actaully I needed to access the DataGridCell control and I managed to do this in the following way:

((sender as CheckBox).TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter).Parent

Comment: You could consider using a helper like this: (sender as CheckBox).FindTemplatedParent<DataGridCell>() for strong typed support. But it's pretty much doing the same thing.